# How to declare variable in vectorWise like SQL Server?

Tags: sql, vectorwise

I am new to `VectorWise` database.

I need to declare variable and pass value in it same like we do in a SQL Server database. Please help me how to do this in VectoreWise database. I am using Squirrel as SQL client.

I need to do it like we do in SQL Server:

```
Declare @name varchar (100)
set @name ='ABC'
select @name
```

Output: `ABC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not particularly familiar with Actian Vector, so I'm not sure if it has a scripting language.  I don't see `declare` as a supported statement.

If you only need a parameter in a single `select`, you can use a CTE.  For your example:

```
with params as (
      select 'ABC' as name
     )
select params.name
from params;
```

I'm not sure if this helps you, but it might.